# How to flatten the YAML structure (List/Map)

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, microservices, kubernetes-helm, spring-cloud-config

Is it possible to convert **hierarchical attributes(Map/List)** to **flattened as linear** `YAML` structure?

For instance, there is a below property defined in a microservice:

```
default:  
  app:
    authentication: 
      security: ${app.authentication.security}
```

The above can be overridden using `kube` object i.e. configMap and as the above property exposed as `${app.authentication.security}`, so inside `configMap` we aren't required to define the entire structure(shown as below), so here we have flattered the `YAML` hierarchy. We are not required to define the entire order.

```
app.authentication.security: false
```

Now, is there any possibility to flatter the `YAML` Map/List, and those `Map/List` properties can be dynamic. Below is the sample structure.

Example:

```
app-ex:
  list: 
    - key1: value
      key2: value
      key3: 
        - list1
        - list2
        - list3
    - key4: value
      key5: value
      key6: 
        - list1
        - list2
        - list3
    .
    .
    - key N
```

The possible expected output can be a flat pattern as below:

```
app-ex.list.key1: val1
app-ex.list.key2: val2
```

Comment: [yq can do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69303779/347964). I don't know why you just drop mid-level keys (such as `app.security` instead of `app.authentication.security`, or the list indexes inside of `list`). If there is some logic behind that, you'll probably need to implement it in a real programming language.

Comment: The first two YAML files you show are very different and do not identify the same data structure.  You could not use them interchangeably in either Kubernetes YAML structures or Helm chart values.  Are you using an application framework (Spring?) that allows either format?

Answer (score 2):

YAML processors can handle and manipulate such files with ease. [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) could be one choice. Here's a solution with it using `tostream` to generate path-value pairs, and `from_entries` to generate the output object:

```bash
yq -y '
  [tostream | select(has(1)) | first |= join(".") | {key: first, value: last}]
  | from_entries
' file.yaml
```

```
app-ex.list.0.key1: value
app-ex.list.0.key2: value
app-ex.list.0.key3.0: list1
app-ex.list.0.key3.1: list2
app-ex.list.0.key3.2: list3
app-ex.list.1.key4: value
app-ex.list.1.key5: value
app-ex.list.1.key6.0: list1
app-ex.list.1.key6.1: list2
app-ex.list.1.key6.2: list3
```

Comment: This works like a charm. I even added a local alias "flatten_yaml" with this exacte same command. Thanks for this